# How to Switch between activities with viewflipper

Tags: android, android-activity, switch-statement, viewflipper

In my android app I am using two activities and I want to make a smooth switch between these activities. I have seen many reference tutorials tells that ViewFlipper can make a smooth switch between views in one activity. So I would like to know if I can use ViewFlipper to switch between activities or Is there any other possible way to do this. At present I am just using button clicks that will start an activity but the switch doesn't look good.

I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Thank You,

Baluk

Answer (score 3):

ViewFlipper can only handle views not Activities. If there is a way to wrap an activity in a view then you might be able to emulate it but I fear the navigation stack would get confusing.

Answer (score 3):

What you actually want to do is to set a custom or just another type of animation for when the `Activity` is being called or ended.

The answer is yes. You can do that using the [overridePendingTransition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition%28int%2C%20int%29) method right after calling one of the `startActivity()` flavors or on the `finish()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I been through the function overridePendingTransition() and came to know that it only works from 2.0 version not under that. As I want my application can be installed on all versions from 1.6, I guess I am out of luck. Is there any other way around to solve the problem. But it is good to know that there is a function for activities too.

Comment: @Balakrishna: You're totally right. I forgot about backwards compatibility.