# viewflipper not calling onCreate of page

Tags: android

I am new to Android development.  I would like to use the viewflipper to bring in pages of my application.  It would go to the next or previous page depending on the recieved gesture event.  I have the gesture working and pages scroll in and out.  Cool!  Problem:  the onCreate of each page doesn't fire and hence I have no click events defined.  Here's what I got:

```
private void BuildViewFlipper(ViewFlipper flipper)
{
    views = new View[2];

    views[0] = GetView(R.layout.ivdosage);

    flipper.addView(views[0], 0);
    views[0].setOnClickListener(CalculationViewer.this); 
    views[0].setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);

    views[1] = GetView(R.layout.ivrate);
    flipper.addView(views[1], 1);
    views[1].setOnClickListener(CalculationViewer.this); 
    views[1].setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);

    flipper.setDisplayedChild(viewIndex); 
}


private View GetView(int id){
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(id, null);        

    return view;
}
```

The views in the above code were Activities.  What am I missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

- Craig

PS: The fixed array for the views was to just get me going and will be updated later.  :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Switch between activities with viewflipper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381723/how-to-switch-between-activities-with-viewflipper)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ViewFlipper` can only host views. You can't include an entire activity in a `ViewFlipper`.

This is a [common question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=multiple+activities+in+viewflipper).